# Keydown event is not working with mozilla

Tags: jquery

I  am posting comments with Enter key press,that is working properly with chrome browser but this code in not working with mozilla browser, I have tested in only with 2 browsers.
I want this code should work with all browsers. What changes are required in following code
I am using jquery 1.8.

```
$(document).on('keydown','.commentbox', function (f) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13)  {                                  

        parentId=$(this).parent().attr("id");

        var idis='#'+parentId;
        var commentOn = $(idis).find('input[name="commentOn"]').val();
        var commentIs = $(idis).find('textarea[name="commentbox"]').val();
        var dataString1 = 'commentOn='+ commentOn
            +'&comment='+commentIs;
        $("#comment").val('');
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({   
            type: "POST",   
            url: "addmessagecomment", 
            dataType: "text html",
            data: dataString1,   
            success: function(data) { 
                var divtoadd="#comments_"+commentOn;
                $(divtoadd).append(data); 
                $(idis).find('textarea[name="commentbox"]').val("");
            }     
        }); 
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make no reference to `event`.  Change

```
$(document).on('keydown','.commentbox', function (f) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13)  {
```

to

```
$(document).on('keydown','.commentbox', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13)  {
```

or

```
$(document).on('keydown','.commentbox', function (f) {
        if (f.keyCode == 13)  {
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$('.commentbox').keyUp(function(event) {
    var keycode=(event.keyCode?event.keyCode:event.which);
    if(keycode=='13'){
      //your function here...
    }
});
```

or .keydown()

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `event` to the method or use `f` as that is getting the event value, the easiest way is just change `f` to `event`:

```
$(document).on('keydown','.commentbox', function (event) {
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RYbNZ/